# Django celery and heroku

Tags: django, asynchronous, heroku, redis, celery

I have configured celery to be deployed in heroku, all Is working well, in fact in my logs at heroku celery is ready to handle the taks. Unfortunately celery doesn't pick my tasks I feel there is some disconnection, can I get some help?

Answer (score 0):

If celery isn't picking up task that means that nothing is talking to its broker.  Make sure that the task producer is talking to the same broker url as the celery worker (the broker url will appear in the first 10-15 lines of the celery logs).